# Why `state` is not faster than `my` while inserting data to database?

Tags: mysql, perl, benchmarking, dbi

Being in the middle of converting databases I tried to use best/fastest inserts. AFAIK, idiomatic mass-insert should prepare the statement handler and after that iterate over data to insert it. Something like that:

```
my $sql = q|INSERT INTO test.table ( value ) VALUES ( ? ) |;  
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );  
for my $val ( 1 .. 1000000 ) {
  $sth->execute( $val );
}
```

I thought that with the help of the `state`-declarator I can refactor this routine into function, something like this:

```
sub sql_state {  
  my ( $val ) = @_;
  state $sql = q|INSERT INTO test.table ( value ) VALUES ( ? ) |;  
  state $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );  
  $sth->execute( $val ) 
    or die "State";  
}
```

So now the `$sql` is initialised once during all inserts and also `$sth` is prepared once, which is the base of enhancement.

During the migrating my database I felt like this improvement did not give me such win as I was hoping. Then I found an article 
[Enemy of the State](http://varlogrant.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/enemy-of-state.html), which rises pretty same question as I asked from my self: why `state` does not give any improvement over `my`?

In commentaries rjbs guesses, that differences would be significant when used `state` and `my` when initializing statement handlers. I did some benchmarking and reach still pretty same conclusion as author of the article: even when in some situations I got `state` a little bit (0.5%) faster, in most cases `my` was at same speed or even faster (up to 9%).

First, I tried with innodb tables, as I needed at my own task:

```
Benchmark: timing 100 iterations of callFor, callMy, callState...
   callFor: 922 wallclock secs ( 7.31 usr +  3.78 sys = 11.09 CPU) @  9.02/s (n=100)
    callMy: 927 wallclock secs ( 6.09 usr +  4.46 sys = 10.55 CPU) @  9.48/s (n=100)
 callState: 922 wallclock secs ( 6.72 usr +  4.62 sys = 11.34 CPU) @  8.82/s (n=100)
```

Those were too slow for wider iterations, so I made some with myisam tables too (1000x1000 = million inserts):

```
Benchmark: timing 1000 iterations of callfor, callmy, callstate...
   callfor: 96 wallclock secs (15.19 usr + 15.50 sys = 30.69 CPU) @ 32.58/s (n=1000)
    callmy: 95 wallclock secs (15.18 usr + 14.90 sys = 30.08 CPU) @ 33.24/s (n=1000)
 callstate: 104 wallclock secs (18.86 usr + 16.15 sys = 35.01 CPU) @ 28.56/s (n=1000)
```

Another run:

```
Benchmark: timing 1000 iterations of callfor, callmy, callstate...
   callfor: 94 wallclock secs (14.90 usr + 14.47 sys = 29.37 CPU) @ 34.05/s (n=1000)
    callmy: 92 wallclock secs (14.77 usr + 14.09 sys = 28.86 CPU) @ 34.65/s (n=1000)
 callstate: 99 wallclock secs (17.66 usr + 15.30 sys = 32.96 CPU) @ 30.34/s (n=1000)
```

Here is my actual code for testing:

```
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;
use ...; # something to get $dbh ...
use Benchmark qw{:all} ;  


sub prepareTable {
  my $dropTable   = q|DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.table|;
  $dbh->do( $dropTable )
    || die "droptable";

  my $createTable = q|
    CREATE TABLE test.table (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `value` varchar(60),
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MYISAM
  |;
  $dbh->do( $createTable )
    || die "createtable";  
}


sub callFor {
  prepareTable();

  my $sql = q|INSERT INTO test.table ( value ) VALUES ( ? ) |;  
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );  

  for my $val ( 1 .. 1000 ) {
    sql_for( $sth, $val );
  }
}

sub callMy {
  prepareTable();

  for my $val ( 1 .. 1000 ) {
    sql_my( $val );
  }
}

sub callState {
  prepareTable();

  for my $val ( 1 .. 1000 ) {
    sql_state( $val );
  }
}

sub sql_for {  
  my ( $sth, $val ) = @_;
  $sth->execute( $val ) 
    or die "For";
}  

sub sql_my {  
  my ( $val ) = @_;
  my $sql = q|INSERT INTO test.table ( value ) VALUES ( ? ) |;  
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );  
  $sth->execute( $val ) 
    or die "My";
}  

sub sql_state {  
  my ( $val ) = @_;
  state $sql = q|INSERT INTO test.table ( value ) VALUES ( ? ) |;  
  state $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );  
  $sth->execute( $val ) 
    or die "State";  
}  


timethese(  
  1000 , {  
    'callFor'   => sub { callFor( ) ; } ,  
    'callMy'    => sub { callFor( ) ; } ,  
    'callState' => sub { callState( ) ; } ,  
  }
);
```

So, why `state` does not win here over `my`? It should easily. Or?

Comment: A little bit offtopic: You know "LOAD DATA INFILE"? Would these be an alternative for you? (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

Comment: If you really want to speed up your inserts, either batch them or use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). Either of these will make a *much* bigger difference than `my` vs. `state`.

Comment: @etalon11: i am aware of database level massinsertion tools, but this is not real alternative in my case, I must mungle data and insert it after that based some migration rules

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: yes, those tools are magnitudes faster but does not suit in my flow for now

Comment: This is an unfair test of `state`, because the speed advantage that it offers is swamped by the associated database operation, especially as you have the `DROP`/`CREATE` as part of your benchmark timing. Every `INSERT` will result in several disk write operations which take many thousands of CPU cycles to execute. This can be mitigated to some extent by starting a transaction, especially so if you can ask MySQL to log that transaction in memory instead of on disk. (That's possible with SQLite, but I don't know MySQL as well.)

Comment: @Borodin: AFAIU, you say that culprits are a) database ops and b) too few inserts ? That's why state and my does not different a much? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes to **a**, but **b** is more like *too many disk operations*. At present you are committing the `INSERT` each time. It is more efficient to accumulate a list of changes for the DB engine to perform and then do them all at once. The bottom line is that benchmarking CPU performance by timing a code segment that includes disk operations is bound to fail.

Comment: @Borodin: I included prepareTable to benchmarking to be sure that every benchmarking iteration has same starting point. And when every test had it, I thought it makes them even. Now I run tests without prepareTable ( only initialized before benchmarking ), results are 91/92/91 sec

Comment: @Borodin: for _b_ there should be auto_commit set to zero and then committing after n iterations?

Comment: @w.k: That sounds right. As I said, I'm not so familiar with MySQL

Comment: If you really want to see the advantage that `state` gives you, you should remove the `execute` call from the subroutines. It's really only saving the time to execute `prepare` more than once.

Comment: By the way, the line `'callMy'    => sub { callFor( ) ; } , ` should be `'callMy'    => sub { callMy( ) ; } , `. But it would be cleaner to avoid the extra level of subroutine call by writing `callFor => \&callFor,` etc.

Comment: Voting to close: typo.

Comment: @w.k Neither of those options requires a separate tool. To do batch/compound inserts, simply combine multiple values in one statement: `INSERT INTO table VALUES (foo, bar), (apple, orange), (pony, unicorn)`. If you crank [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) all the way up, you can send queries of up to 1GB at a time, all from your Perl script. `LOAD DATA INFILE` would be even faster for mass updates; munge your data, write it to a CSV file, and then call `LOAD DATA INFILE`, again all from within your Perl script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to test state vs my, all you really want to benchmark is the cost of a prepare.  I threw in `prepare_cached` since it does the same thing.

```
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;
use DBI;
use Benchmark qw{:all} ;  

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:database=test', '', '',
                       {RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0}
                      );

sub prepareTable {
    my $dropTable   = q|DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.table|;
    $dbh->do( $dropTable );

    my $createTable = q{
    CREATE TABLE test.table (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `value` varchar(60),
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
    };
    $dbh->do( $createTable );
}

prepareTable;
my $sql = q|INSERT INTO test.table ( value ) VALUES ( ? ) |;
cmpthese( -3, {
    'my'                => sub { my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql); return; },  
    'state'             => sub { state $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql); return; },
    'prepare_cached'    => sub { my $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached($sql); return; },
});
__END__
                     Rate             my prepare_cached          state
my                67966/s             --           -73%           -99%
prepare_cached   253414/s           273%             --           -98%
state          11267589/s         16478%          4346%             --
```

This just tells you that not running code is faster than running code.  If you want to find out how much this will impact an actual application, you're on the right path, but you've gummed up your benchmark.  [Here is my improved benchmark](https://gist.github.com/schwern/53fec2012e1c9f37f364).  This makes it more like how code would be run in production (AutoCommit off, RaiseError on), eliminates the table scaffolding, and uses the [generally superior InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb).  Importantly, it removes a lot of extra code and subroutines that will just gum up the benchmark.

The result is, unsurprisingly, that the cost of doing 1000 INSERTs swamps the cost of preparing the INSERT.  The INSERT dominates so much, and its runtime is so unreliable, that it's hard to get a consistent benchmark result out of this.

What if you do less executes per prepare?  The prepare should begin to have a larger effect, and that's just what we see.

```
$EXECUTES_PER_PREPARE = 1;
                  Rate             my prepare_cached          state
my             24722/s             --           -36%           -56%
prepare_cached 38610/s            56%             --           -31%
state          56180/s           127%            46%             --

$EXECUTES_PER_PREPARE = 2;
                  Rate             my prepare_cached          state
my             15949/s             --           -22%           -41%
prepare_cached 20325/s            27%             --           -25%
state          27027/s            69%            33%             --

$EXECUTES_PER_PREPARE = 10;
                 Rate             my prepare_cached          state
my             4405/s             --           -17%           -22%
prepare_cached 5305/s            20%             --            -6%
state          5618/s            28%             6%             --

$EXECUTES_PER_PREPARE = 100;
                Rate             my prepare_cached          state
my             546/s             --            -0%            -1%
prepare_cached 546/s             0%             --            -1%
state          552/s             1%             1%             --
```

Answer (score 10):

You're chasing grasshoppers for protein in a field where there's a cow grazing.

When doing bulk inserts or updates to a database, `autocommit` is *not* your friend if you want speed.  Do a single `commit` when you're done, or throw one in every 1000 records or so.

In the end, saving a few CPU cycles each iteration will mean nothing if you're also waiting around for the Disk I/O of your changes and Index Updates to complete.

Comment: Quite so. I see you're not a vegetarian programmer.

Comment: My benchmark did not confirm your hypothesis. Do you have any ideas, why? For start, I left commiting out on sake of simplicity, but after adding it to flow I am surprised it had no (good) influence.

Comment: An alternative way to do this is to queue your inserts to a file, then load the file to the DB once you reach a certain batch size (we default to 5000 rows at work). This method has been really clean, efficient methodology for us because we can use a simple Perl module to hide that ugliness and just use a `push_row() # queue a row to the file` and `upload() # upload the file to the DB and reset the batch object`

Comment: In a program if mine I switched from autocommit to doing a commit every 1000 inserts and the program was 1000x as fast. But that was against SQLite not MySQL.

Comment: @reinierpost: as you may see in results I present in my answer, autocommit does not have any (good) effect while usin MyISAM tables. Itried also InnoDB tables and here it gives big boost, so it becames almost so fast as with MyISAM.

Comment: @w.k "autocommit does not have any (good) effect while usin MyISAM tables" That's because MyISAM doesn't support transactions, so even with `autocommit` disabled, every statement is committed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Borodin I may announce: `state` still wins over `my`, as should and expected.

I had typo in my code `timethese()` should have a correct line `'callMy'    => sub { callMy( ) ; }` and no questions to ask.

After fixing that and removing database ops, I got much colourful results:

```
Benchmark: timing 1000 iterations of callFor, callMy, callState...
   callFor: 85 wallclock secs (15.60 usr + 13.38 sys = 28.98 CPU) @ 34.51/s (n=1000)
    callMy: 162 wallclock secs (64.36 usr + 21.17 sys = 85.53 CPU) @ 11.69/s (n=1000)
 callState: 86 wallclock secs (15.83 usr + 13.55 sys = 29.38 CPU) @ 34.04/s (n=1000)
```

Then I set `$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;` and used `$dbh->commit();` after iteration:

```
Benchmark: timing 1000 iterations of callFor, callMy, callState...
   callFor: 87 wallclock secs (16.57 usr + 14.50 sys = 31.07 CPU) @ 32.19/s (n=1000)
    callMy: 166 wallclock secs (66.39 usr + 21.92 sys = 88.31 CPU) @ 11.32/s (n=1000)
 callState: 87 wallclock secs (16.50 usr + 14.21 sys = 30.71 CPU) @ 32.56/s (n=1000)
```

Seems to me, `autocommit` does not have good influence here.

Leaving my answer here for future reference.